# Detect possible router attack attempt

Tags: wifi, attack-prevention, router, spoofing

I have huge problem with my router: Sagem F@st 3202.

Here are some Security log events:

> Inbound Traffic   |   Blocked - Default policy   |   TCP
> XX.XX.XX.XXX:80->XX.X.XX.XX:51707 on ppp0 [repeated 3 times, last time on Apr 23 02:32:08 2014]
>
> Inbound Traffic   |   Blocked - Spoofing protection   |   IGMP
> 192.168.4.1->224.0.0.1 on eth2
>
> Inbound Traffic   |   Blocked   |   Packet invalid in connection, tcp
> reset attack is suspected: TCP [repeated 2 times, last time on Apr 23
> 02:35:02 2014]

The events repeat all the time during last 24 hours.

Could you help me to identify the attack?
It would be very helpful to define the attacker. Is it possible that it's some kind of wardriving? Is it a random or planned attempt?

Comment: How do you know it's a man-in-the-middle attack? Do you even know what that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go and do a GeoIP lookup on the IP address, given that it's not spoofed (which 9/10 times it is).  If the IP isn't hopping too much, you could create a drop rule to block traffic from that IP.  You may even be able to drop the subnet given all the source IP's are in that subnet.  It seems like they are throwing random attacks at you.  There isn't a lot of information to go on with this post.  Perhaps you have more log entries with different information?  Are there any IP addresses that you can provide that are not your own?

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. The list of IPs is huge, and they have random GeoIP results from whole world (something like Tor). I'm preparing much more data to present.

Could you help me to recognize the type and purpose of the attack? It's very important for me. Is it a planned surveillance or just a random problem. It started several hours after I configured OTR messaging in my client program. I use the computer and Internet connection only in legal way, and I've started using private chatting and browsing only to protect my privacy. Should I call the police and ask them for help?

Comment: Also, I would like to point that I have had some problems with stalker, and it may be the second attempt of stalking and violating my privacy. This time I would like to immediately perform appropriate actions.

Comment: Important note: currently the WiFi is turned off, only Bluetooth stays on (the router backend has no option do disable it). I use only ethernet connection. The router is also resetting very often, sometimes more than 10 times per hour.

Comment: David, I would recommend getting yourself a wired only modem. Bluetooth is practically less secure than WiFi. The attack looks like it's a TCP reset attack where the attacker is purposefully closing connections. I do recognize that your logs show some spoofing detections, but without IP addresses (at least first 2 octets) I can't tell much.

Comment: Apr 23 03:43:49 2014 Inbound Traffic Blocked - Default policy TCP 93.191.101.181:50400->X.X.X.X:8088 on ppp0 

Apr 23 03:43:48 2014 Inbound Traffic Blocked - Default policy TCP 93.191.101.181:65176->X.X.X.X:8088 on ppp0 

Apr 23 03:43:46 2014 Inbound Traffic Blocked - Default policy TCP 93.191.101.181:62069->X.X.X.X:8090 on ppp0 

Apr 23 03:43:45 2014 Inbound Traffic Blocked - Default policy TCP 93.191.101.181:60499->X.X.X.X:8090 on ppp0

Comment: Apr 23 03:43:25 2014 Inbound Traffic Blocked - Packet invalid in connection TCP 90.84.55.24:80->192.168.1.12:54609 on ppp0
Apr 23 03:43:13 2014 Inbound Traffic Blocked - Packet invalid in connection TCP 90.84.55.24:80->192.168.1.12:54591 on ppp0
Apr 23 03:36:35 2014 Inbound Traffic Blocked - Packet invalid in connection tcp reset attack is suspected: TCP 90.84.60.65:443->192.168.1.12:54009 on ppp0
Apr 23 03:33:24 2014 Inbound Traffic Blocked - Default policy TCP 213.189.48.208:80->X.X.X.X:53496 on ppp0

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments (stackexchange restrictions). Would the information be enough or should I post more?

Comment: This latest log file looks like port probes. Essentially just port scans. These could be random as things like this happen in the wild, but it could be targeted. The attacker is making a lot of noise if they are actually attacking you.

Comment: They are still attacking. Is it possible that single, normal computer skilled person is doing this? The attack is very intensive. Will wired modem solve the problem?

Comment: My opinion is it is still an NMAP scan. It's a standard port scan method to hit a firewall with a reset packet or ack packet.

Comment: No, the wired modem will not fix this issue. I would contact your ISP and work with them to have the offending traffic stopped.

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank you for your help. Can the NMAP scan use Bluetooth connection? The eth2 port is the second, empty Ethernet socket in my routed. It looks like its just only attempt without any success?

Comment: I understand. It looks like I'm the target of the attack, but is it possible to keep the scan without having static IP of mine or some other data? Sorry for asking so many questions but its early morning in my timezone and I'm still dealing with the problem.

Comment: No problem. Bluetooth is very insecure. In the long run, I would replace the router anyway as I'm personally not a fan of bluetooth. Bluetooth has a very short range of approximately 30 ft. If you are getting connections on that, someone is very close in proximity to you.

Comment: Sure. Unless you specifically requested a static IP, you probably have a DHCP address. If you work with your ISP, they can get you a new dhcp address. If you do have a static, you will be an easy target going forward as attackers know where to find you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The range is definitely short. Could it be extended by some devices like directional antenna? I think it's possible that the attacker is using BT.

Comment: I have dynamic IP. I will contact the ISP immediately. Should I inform any law enforcement authorities too?

Comment: It certainly can be extended and repeaters do exist for bluetooth. If you're really concerned, I would recommend looking up how to make a DIY faraday cage. Bluetooth uses the 2.4Ghz wireless spectrum.

Comment: You could, but I doubt they will be too concerned unless you have an existing restraining order or something that shows a history of you being a victim of targeted crimes.

Comment: Making a DIY faraday cage is brilliant idea. Your advices are very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your ISP. Please mark my answer if you find it helpful. Feel free to comment if you have additional information you would like help with.